# What is the best way to "put" in Rails Resque worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I am calling puts statements like this:

```
puts "something"
```

Within my Rails Resque workers. What is the best way to read this output real time? tail development.log?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could always try to use the `Logger`:

```
Logger.info "Something"
# Or
Logger.debug "Something"
# Or
Logger.error "Something"
```

These will definitely show up in your logs. :)

Comment: I get `undefined method `debug' for Logger:Class`, when I try this. `Rails.logger`, on the other hand, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Log4r:

In config/environments/*.rb

```
  #format of message in logger
  format = Log4r::PatternFormatter.new(:pattern => "%d - [%l]:\t%m.")
  # log configuration
  configlog = {
  "filename" => "log/your_name.log",
  "max_backups" => 28, # 7days * 4 files of 6 hours
  "maxtime" => 21600, # 6 hours in sec
  "maxsize" => 10485760, # 10MB in bytes
  "trunc" => false
  }
  rolling = Log4r::RollingFileOutputter.new("rolling",configlog)
  rolling.formatter = format
  config.logger = Log4r::Logger.new("your_name.log")
  config.logger.add(rolling)
```

Then in your code:

```
Logger.info "output"
Logger.debug "output"
```

In your_name.log you will see:

```
2013-08-07 10:00:47 - [INFO]: output
2013-08-07 10:00:47 - [DEBUG]: output
```